# How can the keyboard backlight be prevented from switching on when a power supply is connected in Ubuntu 18.04 running the MATE desktop environment?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, thinkpad, mate, backlight

If I have the power supply cable connected to the ThinkPad X390 here with the keyboard backlight switched off and then I disconnect and then reconnect the power cable, the keyboard backlight switches on. How can this be prevented? How can the state of the keyboard backlight be maintained?

Comment: Can you show `ls -al /sys/class/leds/` My thinkpad has no keyboard backloght.

Comment: Check for a keyboard backlighting setting in your BIOS.